# Angular ng-model expression

Tags: html, angularjs, math, rounding, angularjs-ng-model

I want to ask how can I round the numbers inside an input, using **angularjs**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="value1"/>
```

I want the number to show 2 decimals with rounding.

Can you help please

Comment: If in case you want to show for it, try angular filter:  <span> **{{value1 | number:2}}** </span>

Comment: @wZVanG I think this will add comma in number..

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-change:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="value1" ng-change="roundNumber()" />

$scope.roundNumber = function(){
    $scope.value1 = Math.round($scope.value1 * 100) / 100;
};

//call function once at bottom of controller for initial run
$scope.roundNumber();
```

Or create a directive to do it if this is going to be a common functionality you want

Comment: Works and save watchers.

Comment: what about the initial run? is it going to be called and rounded the number ?

Comment: You can call the function in your controller and it will be called when the controller is initialized and update the number initially

Answer (score 1):

Use `$watch` in this case will be more appropriate, It will tend to format value on initial load also.

**Markup**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="value1"/>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.$watch('value1',function(newVal, oldVal){
    if((newVal != oldVal))
       $scope.value1 = newVal?  newVal.toFixed(2): 0;
});
```

Comment: What is `$watch` actually watching?

Comment: @softvar that my bad..Thanks for heads up..it actually watch on `value1`..I missed that `string ` LOL :D

Comment: In this case, I need to add watch for each field I need to round in the code. right ? I have too many text fields and too many states

Comment: In some cases, I don't have binding, it's a total field, so its like
<input type="number" ng-value="value1+value2"/>

I need to round and have always 2 deciamls (10.00)